# Помогите посчитать перевести строку 2+2 в число

Tags: java

Я задал в аргумент (args) строку 2+2 и хочу чтобы прога написала в консоли 4, но вылетает ошибка.
P.S я только учусь

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(args[0]));

}
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2+2"
 at java.base/java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:68)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:652)
 at java.base/java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:770)
 at CalculatorArgs.main(CalculatorArgs.java:6)

Comment: ну что тут непонятного? Вы строку пробуете перевести в число. ПРимеры чисел - `456`, `66`, `51` - это числа. А вот это `2+2`- не число, а выражение. Раз это не число, то такую строку перевести в число нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Стандартная задача. Функция `eval` принимает на вход выражение и возвращает его значение. Сам процесс вычисления разделён на два этапа: разборка выражения на токены - минимальные элементы имеющие самостоятельное значение, и собственно вычисление.

Разборка на токены сделана в методе `tokenize`. Внутри регулярное выражение, которое выделяет числа и символы '+-*/()'.

Вычисление делает класс `Calc`. Методы: `op` - сюда отправляют операции, `num` - cюда числа, `eval` - его вызывают в конце и получают значение выражения.

`Calc` реализует [алгоритм сортировочной станции](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC_%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8). Там внутри два стека: один для чисел, второй для операций. Я не буду тут его повторять, потребуется много места. Но рекомендую почитать - это классика алгоритмов, её стоит изучить. Приятно понимать как компьютеры разбирают алгебраические выражения. Ссылки: [shunting-yard algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) и [обратная польская запись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C). В прошлом веке были популярны калькуляторы на обратной польской нотации, её проще обрабатывать когда мало памяти и процессор слабый.

`apply` - сердце калькулятора, стековая машина. Это что-то вроде ассемблера в котором всего четыре операции: выбрать из стека два числа и поместить обратно их сумму, тоже про разность, произведение и отношение.

Конечно никакой обработки ошибок нет. Учебный пример, полагаемся на пользователя.

Примеры использования. Выражения со скобками нужно брать в кавычки, это особенность работы командной строки:

```
$ java Calculator 2+2
4
$ java Calculator 2+2*2
6
$ java Calculator "(2+2)*2"
8
$ java Calculator "(11+2*3)/7"
2
$ java Calculator "(11+2*3)/7-3"
-1
```

Сама программа, 95 строк:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Stack;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Calculator {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(eval(args[0]));
    }

    public static int eval(String expr) {
        Calc c = new Calc();
        for (String token : tokenize(expr)) {
            if (token.length() == 1 && "+-*/()".contains(token)) {
                c.op(token.charAt(0));
            } else {
                c.num(Integer.parseInt(token));
            }
        }
        return c.eval();
    }

    public static List<String> tokenize(String expr) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[-+\\*/()]|[\\d]+").matcher(expr);
        while (m.find()) {
            list.add(m.group());
        }
        return list;
    }

    private static class Calc {
        private Stack<Integer> nums = new Stack<Integer>();
        private Stack<Character> ops = new Stack<Character>();

        public void op(char c) {
            if (c == '(') {
                ops.push(c);
            } else if (c == ')') {
                while (true) {
                    char cc = ops.pop();
                    if (cc == '(') {
                        break;
                    }
                    apply(cc);
                }
            } else {
                while (!ops.empty() && priority(ops.peek()) >= priority(c)) {
                    apply(ops.pop());
                }
                ops.push(c);
            }
        }

        public void num(int v) {
            nums.push(v);
        }

        public int eval() {
            while (!ops.empty()) {
                apply(ops.pop());
            }
            return nums.pop();
        }

        private int priority(char c) {
            if (c == '+') { return 1; }
            if (c == '-') { return 1; }
            if (c == '*') { return 2; }
            if (c == '/') { return 2; }
            return 0;
        }

        private void apply(char c) {
            if (c == '+') {
                int b = nums.pop();
                int a = nums.pop();
                nums.push(a + b);
            } else if (c == '-') {
                int b = nums.pop();
                int a = nums.pop();
                nums.push(a - b);
            } else if (c == '*') {
                int b = nums.pop();
                int a = nums.pop();
                nums.push(a * b);
            } else if (c == '/') {
                int b = nums.pop();
                int a = nums.pop();
                nums.push(a / b);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;

ScriptEngineManager sem = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine js = sem.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
System.out.println(js.eval(args[0]));
```

Comment: Ваше решение не работает: Cannot invoke "javax.script.ScriptEngine.eval(String)" because "js" is null

Comment: https://onlinegdb.com/1sN5Fed91 [С аргументами](https://onlinegdb.com/ku3NsMPMr)